# How to hide table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I get some values from database and i want to show theme in a table which is working but what if I want to DELETE or HIDE a ROW if value == 0 ? I couldn't figure it out how to do it ... please help me here :

**This is my HTML code**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id ="">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Type</th><th>days</th>
                            <tr> 
                                <td class="lavorato">
                                    Lavorato
                                </td>
                                <td class="lavorato_detail">
                                    ...
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td class="ferie">
                                    Ferie
                                </td>
                                <td class="ferie_detail">
                                    ...
                                </td>
                            </tr> </table>
```

**This my Json**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn-modal').click(function() {
    var idts = $(this).data("idts");
    $('.lavorato_detail, .permesso_detail, .ferie_detail, .malattia_detail, .aspettativa_detail, .nonretribuito_detail').html('...');
    if(idts == "")
    {
        $('#details').modal();
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'count.php', 
        type: "POST",
        data: "idts="+idts,
        success: function(data)
        {
            dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(dataArray , function(i, v) {
                switch(v['desc'])
                {
                    case 'Lavorato':
                    $('.permesso_detail').html(v['sum_permesso']+ ' Ore');
                    $('.lavorato_detail').html(v['count_giorno']);
                    break;

                    case 'Ferie': // here i want to add changes 
                    $('.ferie_detail').html(v['count_giorno']);
                    break;


                }
            });

            $('#details').modal();
        },
    });
});
```

});

for example I want to say  ::: case 'Ferie': If == 0 { hide all row related to FERIE in HTML } else { do something else}

Comment: .hide(); doesn't work?

Comment: No its not working ...

Comment: U may be mistaken at selector.

Comment: Use `.each()` for traversing html table- like `$.each($("#tableDemo tbody").find("tr"), function() {.....}`

Comment: I don't know ... see my comment bellow the first answer ... is it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ferie_detail').parents("tr:first").hide();
```

Try this....

Comment: `$.fn.closest` will also do this :)

Comment: Its not working . Se if I made mistake somewhere  ::: case 'Ferie': 
                                                    if ('Ferie' == 0){
                                                      $('.ferie_detail').parents("tr:first").hide();
                                                    } else {
                                                        $('.ferie_detail').html(v['count_giorno']);
                                                }

Comment: can you plz explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: try .css('display','hidden') instead of .hide().

Comment: Its a simple table that shows activity off employees during a month , in Italian language FERIE means holidays Here I want if my employees went to a holiday show number of days in a table (which is working correctly right now) but if they didn't go holidays i want to hidden that row from my html table . @Simranjeet Singh

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
$.each($("#tableDemo tbody").find(".ferie"), function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == "ferie")
           $(this).hide();
        else
             $(this).show();                
    });
```

Make sure that give your table id as `id="tableDemo"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
$('.ferie_detail').parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the id of the table but if that's not what your are looking for this line works.

$('body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').hide();

`<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>hide demo</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id ="">
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th><th>days</th>
        <tr> 
            <td class="lavorato">
                Lavorato
            </td>
            <td class="lavorato_detail">
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td class="ferie">
                Ferie
            </td>
            <td class="ferie_detail">
                ...
            </td>
        </tr> </table>
    </html>`

Hope this helps... =)